# HTML JavaScript Buttons not working, as well as a baffling Error

Tags: javascript, html

everyone.

I'm currently building a Javascript HTML page. However I cannot get the buttons to work and I'm not sure why. 
There's also an 'Expected ";"' error in the Javascript section. I've commented where the error occurs.

Here's the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

        function btnClear_onclick() {
            fdegrees.focus();
            fdegrees.value = "";
            cdegrees.value = "";
        }

        function checkNumber(theTextBox) {
            //check the text box for a value, if none alert user that there is a invalid entry
            //the 'isNaN' checks to see if there is a number entered in the text box, and returns a boolean value
            //as needed. (false is invalid, and true is valid)
            //the 'isNaN' stands for 'is Not a Number'
            if (theTextBox.value == "" || isNaN(theTextBox.value) || theTextBox.value.toFixed(1)) {
                alert("Invalid Value in Text Box");
                theTextBox.select();
                return false;
            }
            //continue on with the calculations if valid using the btn Event.
            else
                return true;
        }

        function btnCompute_onclick(theForm) {

            if (checkNumber(theForm.fdegrees)) {
                num1 = parseInt(theForm.fdegrees.value);
                answer = (num1 - 32) * 5 / 9;
                theForm.cdegrees.value = answer;
                }
            else if (checkNumber(theForm.cdegrees)) {//error happens here on the square bracket
                num2 = parseInt(theForm.cdegrees.value);
                answer = num2 * 9 / 5 + 32;
                theForm.fdegrees.value = answer;
                }


        }

// ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p style="text-align: center">
        Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter</p>
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 280px">
        Degrees Fahrenheit:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="fdegrees" type="text" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 280px">
        Degrees Celsius:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="cdegrees" type="text" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 280px">
        <input id="btnCompute" type="button" value="Compute" onclick="btnCompute_onclick(this.form)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="btnClear_onclick(this.form)" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Missing `if` on that line

Comment: First thing I'd do is use the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, drop the `<![CDATA[` declarations and the `language` and `type` script attributes and join the rest of us in 2013 ;)

Comment: Hahaha, I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010, no chance, not just yet.
@Musa The buttons still don't work, so I can't test the functions out.

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy What does your IDE have to do with anything?

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure, but I'm doing this for a class so I'll stick with the given resources, and once I've figured out this error, I can test and edit my code as needed.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie else if (checkNumber(theForm.cdegrees)) **{** I've bolded the square bracket

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy That's called a *brace*. A square bracket is `[` or `]`

Comment: JSFiddle here for those who want to play around though I've moved the script to the bottom of `<body>` - http://jsfiddle.net/3x86T/

Comment: @Phil ah, I stand corrected. My bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have no `<form>` so can't use `this.form`. Add a `<form>` tag around your inputs.
2. Your form inputs need `name` attributes to be accessed by the `Form` element
3. You should add `theForm` as an argument to your `btnClear_onclick()` function and access the inputs via that
4. `Input.value` returns a string. Strings do not have a method `toFixed()`. This is a method of `Number`

This is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/3x86T/1/

Answer (score 2):

the `else` keyword doesn't use a statement:

`if(...) { } else { }`

that line should be `else if` :

`else if(checkNumber(theForm.cdegrees)) {...`

Comment: +1 but the OP has updated their code with an `else if` so this may no longer be the problem

Comment: @Phil i see, copy/pasting the above code in the console shows no syntax error now so I wonder if it's fixed.